# Why I can't merge the columns together

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

My goal is to transform the array to DataFrame, and the error occurred only at the columns=...

```
housing_extra = pd.DataFrame(housing_extra_attribs,
                index=housing_num.index,
                columns=[housing.columns,'rooms_per_household', 'population_per_household', 'bedrooms_per_room'])
```

Consequently, it returns

```
AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 4, # tot_items: 12
```

It said I only do input 4 columns, but the  `housing.columns` itself has 9 columns

here, when I run `housing.columns` ;

```
Index(['longitude', 'latitude', 'housing_median_age', 'total_rooms',
      'total_bedrooms', 'population', 'households', 'median_income',
      'ocean_proximity'],
     dtype='object')
```

So, My question is how can I merge the existed column which is `housing.columns` with the 3 new columns;  `['rooms_per_household', 'population_per_household', 'bedrooms_per_room']` together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Index.union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) to add a list of columns to existing dataframe columns:

```
columns= housing.columns.union(
['rooms_per_household', 'population_per_household', 'bedrooms_per_room'],
sort=False)
```

Or convert to list and then add the remaining columns as list:

```
columns = (housing.columns.tolist() + 
 ['rooms_per_household', 'population_per_household', 'bedrooms_per_room'])
```

Then:

```
housing_extra = pd.DataFrame(housing_extra_attribs,
                index=housing_num.index,
                columns=columns)
```

---

Some example:
Assume this df:

```
df = pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()
print(df.columns)
#Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

When you pass this into a list:

```
[df.columns,'E','F','G']
```

you get:

```
[Index(['userId', 'column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3'], dtype='object'),'E','F','G']
```

v/s when you use union:

```
df.columns.union(['E','F','G'],sort=False)
```

You get:

```
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: but there is a mistake of the wrong syntax: from tolist() to to_list()

Comment: @Wallika. thanks for the comment. tolist() also works for me in version 0. 25.1. I think it might have changed with version. Glad you could figure this though.